# Group array together making the common value a key

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [c_id] => 1 
        [semester] => 1 
        [level] => 100 
        [code] => ges 101 
        [title] => english language 
        [units] => 3 
        [lecturer] => aboh 
        [department] => philosophy 
        [matric] => 487 
        [session] => 2011/2012 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [c_id] => 2 
        [semester] => 1 
        [level] => 100 
        [code] => phi 102 
        [title] => aristotelian logic 
        [units] => 3 
        [lecturer] => offor 
        [department] => philosophy 
        [matric] => 487 
        [session] => 2011/2012 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [c_id] => 3 
        [semester] => 1 
        [level] => 100 
        [code] => ges 102 
        [title] => methodology 
        [units] => 3 
        [lecturer] => akunne 
        [department] => philosophy 
        [matric] => 487 
        [session] => 2011/2012 
    )  
    [16] => Array ( 
        [c_id] => 28 
        [semester] => 1 
        [level] => 200
        [code] => phi 209 
        [title] => introduction to epistemology 
        [units] => 3 
        [lecturer] => akunne 
        [department] => philosophy 
        [matric] => 487 
        [session] => 2011/2012 
    ) 
    [17] => Array ( 
        [c_id] => 29 
        [semester] => 1 
        [level] => 200 
        [code] => phi 207 
        [title] => philosophy of mind 
        [units] => 3 
        [lecturer] => akoleowo 
        [department] => philosophy 
        [matric] => 487 
        [session] => 2011/2012 
    ) 
    [18] => Array ( 
        [c_id] => 30 
        [semester] => 1 
        [level] => 200 
        [code] => rcs 211 
        [title] => introduction to old testament 
        [units] => 2 
        [lecturer] => acha 
        [department] => philosophy 
        [matric] => 487 
        [session] => 2011/2012 
    )
    [19] => Array ( 
        [c_id] => 31 
        [semester] => 1 
        [level] => 200 
        [code] => phi 204 
        [title] => philosophy of nature 
        [units] => 3 
        [lecturer] => mbukanma 
        [department] => philosophy 
        [matric] => 487 
        [session] => 2011/2012 
    )
```

I want to Group array together making the common value a key like making 100 a key and getting all the values of array with 100 in the particular layer it falls.

Comment: What language it is ?

Comment: i should be solved in php. solution will really be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if my english is too bad but I read your question many times and I still can't understand what you're trying to explain.

Comment: i want all the everything for 100 to be grouped together, everything for 200 to be together and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = ... //your array
$groupedArray = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $groupedArray[$item['level']][] = $item;
}
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: you just made my day. thank you so much. i tried vote you up but ain't get enought reputation to that. but all thumbs up for you.